# HTML, javascript canvas at Parcheesi game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a Parcheesi Online to a subjet at the university but I'm having some problems with it. This is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
  <script src='/Parchis/js/board.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
tablero();
fichas();
amarillo[4] = {
  x: posicion[1].x,
  y: posicion[1].y,
  x2: posicion[1].x2,
  y2: posicion[1].y2,
  x3: posicion[1].x3,
  y3: posicion[1].y3,
  casilla: 1
}; //meta verde
amarillo[3] = {
  x: posicion[2].x,
  y: posicion[2].y,
  x2: posicion[2].x2,
  y2: posicion[2].y2,
  x3: posicion[2].x3,
  y3: posicion[2].y3,
  casilla: 2
}; //meta verde
amarillo[2] = {
  x: posicion[3].x,
  y: posicion[3].y,
  x2: posicion[3].x2,
  y2: posicion[3].y2,
  x3: posicion[3].x3,
  y3: posicion[3].y3,
  casilla: 3
}; //meta verde
amarillo[1] = {
  x: posicion[8].x,
  y: posicion[8].y,
  x2: posicion[8].x2,
  y2: posicion[8].y2,
  x3: posicion[8].x3,
  y3: posicion[8].y3,
  casilla: 8
}; //meta verde

var num = 0;
var selec = 0;

var ficha = new Ficha("1", amarillo[1].x, amarillo[1].y, 14, 'rgba(255,255,0, 1)');
ficha.draw(context);
var ficha = new Ficha("2", amarillo[2].x, amarillo[2].y, 14, 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)');
ficha.draw(context);
var ficha = new Ficha("3", amarillo[3].x, amarillo[3].y, 14, 'rgba(0,255,0, 1)');
ficha.draw(context);
var ficha = new Ficha("4", amarillo[4].x, amarillo[4].y, 14, 'rgba(0,0,255, 1)');
ficha.draw(context);

function dado() {
  num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML = num;
  window.addEventListener('click', draw, false);
  tablero();
  fichas();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function draw(e) {
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
      var casilla = amarillo[i].casilla;
      var selec = casilla + num;
      var raton = getMousePos(canvas, e);
      var right = posicion[selec].x + 17;
      var left = posicion[selec].x - 17;
      var top = posicion[selec].y + 17;
      var bot = posicion[selec].y - 17;
      var ficha = new Ficha("FD", posicion[selec].x, posicion[selec].y, 17, 'rgba(191,191,191, 1)');
      ficha.draw(context);

      if (raton.x < right && raton.x > left && raton.y > bot && raton.y < top ) {
        amarillo[i].x = posicion[selec].x;
        amarillo[i].y = posicion[selec].y;
        amarillo[i].casilla = selec;

        ficha1=amarillo[i].casilla;
        ficha2=amarillo[j].casilla;
        if(i!=j && ficha1==ficha2){
          amarillo[j].x = posicion[selec].x3;
          amarillo[j].y = posicion[selec].y3;
          amarillo[i].x = posicion[selec].x2;
          amarillo[i].y = posicion[selec].y2;
      }
        else{
          amarillo[i].x = posicion[selec].x;
          amarillo[i].y = posicion[selec].y;
        }
        window.removeEventListener('click', draw);
        tablero();
        fichas();
      }
    }
  }
  var ficha = new Ficha("1", amarillo[1].x, amarillo[1].y, 14, 'rgba(255,255,0, 1)');
  ficha.draw(context);
  var ficha = new Ficha("2", amarillo[2].x, amarillo[2].y, 14, 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)');
  ficha.draw(context);
  var ficha = new Ficha("3", amarillo[3].x, amarillo[3].y, 14, 'rgba(0,255,0, 1)');
  ficha.draw(context);
  var ficha = new Ficha("4", amarillo[4].x, amarillo[4].y, 14, 'rgba(0,0,255, 1)');
  ficha.draw(context);
}
  window.addEventListener('click', draw, false);
  </script>
  <button onclick='dado()'>   Tira   </button>
  <p id='numero'></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I'm going to explain how it works, and which are my problems:

I use the amarillo array to save the position (which is saved in the board.js file) of each token, it has a central position, a left position and a right position for each rectangle.

With the function dado I'm creating a virtual dice, that number will be added to the position of each token, drawed on the board and with the mouse you will click to which position you'd like to move your token.

My problems are that sometimes, when I choose a position where there is a token, the token that was originally there disappears instead of changing it to the left position, but sometimes it doesn't happens and works fine.

The other problem that I'm having is that when the dice tokens are drawed at the board when I click at the token, the new is drawed at the correct place, but I don't know why, there is another dice token draw at the new position + dice number.

If you need more code or info, ask me for it.

Thanks!!